# Sending data to the controller through Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am finding it difficult to send data to the controller through Ajax post since the object to be sent to the controller cannot be used within the ajax post because of the structure of my code.I am using knockout for data-binding the click event of the Update button.

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
var provider = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.providerID = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.ProviderID);
    self.firstName = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.FirstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.LastName);
    self.contactEmail = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.ContactEmail);
    self.NPI = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.NPI);

    self.updateProviderDetails = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Provider/UpdateProviderDetails/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { providerForUpdate }, -- Cant send this
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.url) {
                    location.href = result.url;
                }
            }
        });
    };

    self.cancelEdits = function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Cancel?")) {
            window.location.href = "/Provider/ShowTheListOfProviders";
        }
    };
}; //End of Constructor.

var providerForUpdate = new provider();
ko.applyBindings(providerForUpdate);
 });
```

On the clck of Update Button,I am calling the 'updateProviderDetails' method.

HTML

```
 @model Greenway.Demo.DataAccess.Entity.Provider

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1 class="col-sm-offset-2">Edit Provider Details:</h1>
    <br />
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="editProviderDetailsForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="firstName" name="firstName" data-bind="value:firstName , event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Last Name" id="lastName" name="lastName" data-bind="value:lastName ,event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }">
            </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button type="Submit" data-bind="click: updateProviderDetails" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            <button type="button" data-bind="click: cancelEdits" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var providerEditInfo = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
 </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_Scripts/Shared/Functions.js"></script>
```

Could someone guide me on how I can send the data to the controller with this code structure.I can't put updateProviderDetails outside the constructor because otherwise, I can't bind it.

Comment: what is providerforUpdate? you haven't defined it

Comment: Its to update the details of the provider.Fields of the form are bound to the properties of the viewmodel.PLease see my edit

Answer (score 0):

What I am getting from your code, providerEditInfo seems to be js object. Create observable object instead of making individual property.

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(providerEditInfo, null, self.observableProvider);
```

Use self.observableProvider for binding as this will have all the properties of providerEditInfo made observable and when done send this observable to controller as

```
data: { ko.toJS(self.observableProvider)}
```

Comment: The form is used for update.So,initially I am getting the details of the provider,converting it to JSON and bind it to the form.For that purpose I am using providerEditInfo.The conversion to JSON is happening at the bottom of the HTML page.Please see my edit.But on update,I have to use providerforUpdate,I think.

Comment: what you are trying to do is making individual property as separate observable and binding controls to them instead what you should be doing is making complete object and use with binding. Then for update, send the same object by mapping it to JS. I think you need to see more tutorial of Knockout.

Comment: Actually I tried this.But I am not able to access any of the properties like Firest name,lastname  through self.observableProvider.firstname does not give me firstname.Could you please guide me some more.Total noob to client side programming.

Comment: Just one question,Dont i have to initialise each field with a value if I use observableProvider

Comment: once properties are observable, you need to access them as self.observableProvider.firstname() like a function. I would suggest you see this tutorial: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail.

Comment: self.observableProvider.firstname()  seems to not be working since an alert to this statement basically stops the fields from getting populated.Just thought you would like to know.